# How to post to another php file in javascript when using Laravel framework?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have created a polygon maker that I used to create a polygon of certain region. I want to post the polygon's lat, lng and region name to another php file and insert data to mysql from that file. Previously I've used native php to create similar, and it works. But when I try to do this in Laravel, its not working. I've only been learning Laravel for few days, so I'm not really familiar with Laravel.

This is the code in Javascript:

```
var polycoords = '';
turf.flip(layer.toGeoJSON()).geometry.coordinates[0].forEach(function(item) 
{
polycoords += item[0] + ',' + item[1] + "|";
});

function titikk(polycoords,kecamatan) {
   $.ajaxSetup({async:false});  

   var returnData = null;  
   $.post("code.php", { polycoords: polycoords, kecamatan: kecamatan }, 
   function(data) {
   returnData = data;   
   });
   $.ajaxSetup({async:true});  
   return returnData;  
}
titiks = titikk(polycoords,kecamatan);
```

code.php

```
require_once("conn.php");
$x ="";
$y ="";
$polycoords =  $_POST["polycoords"];
$kecamatan =  $_POST["kecamatan"];

$pieces = explode("|", $polycoords);
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($pieces);$i++)
{
    $data = array();
    $data = explode(",", $pieces[$i]);

    $x .= $data[0].",";
    $y .= $data[1].",";

}
$x = substr($x,0,-2);
$y = substr($y,0,-2);

$input_kecamatan = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into `kecamatan` (`nama`,`lat`,`lng`) 
    values ('$kecamatan','$x','$y')");
```

I put code.php in public folder.

Is it right to do this in Laravel? Or do I need to use post in a route? Can anyone suggest how to make this work or another way that still can get what I want? Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Using Laravel you will need to create a route for your post request and ideally a controller to contain the code from code.php.

```
Route::post('url-name/', 'CodeController@code')->name('route-name')

// or without controller

Route::post('url-name', function($request) {
    // Code Here
    return response()->json($response);
})
```

You can find more information on the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#basic-routing

And for inserting data into the database you should use Eloquent or the Query Builder. Eloquent requires creating a model first.

```
// Eloquent
    Kecamatan::create([
    'lat' => $lat,
    'long' => $long,
    'nama' => $nama    
])

// Query Builder

DB::table('kecamatan')->insert([
    'lat' => $lat,
    'long' => $long,
    'nama' => $nama    
])
```

You can find all this at

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent

Answer (score 0):

Although its not recommended but you can put your file(code.php) in your public folder and use it.

The Proper way will be create a new route make a new controller or action and try to use that code in that controller or action. That way you dont have to use mysql_query you can use [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent) or [Database Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries).